# Calling another useCallback function from useCallback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple code,

> onClick -> doSomething() -> testFunction()

`doSomething()` is a useCallback function and it calls another useCallback function, `testFunction()`

Due to `doSomething()` is declared first and `testFunction()` is declared after, I am getting stale `testFunction()` when `doSomething()` is called.

Shouldn't `doSomething()` refers to the latest `testFunction()`, as I added `[testFunction]` as its dependency?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-18gpk?file=/src/index.js

```js
/**
 * To simulate, click on Increment until the count is 2,
 * and click on Testbutton which console.log(count) and the value is 0.
 * Even though the count value is > 0, console.log(count) still gives 0
 */
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  let testFunction;
  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    // Do something else here
    testFunction();
  }, [testFunction]);

  testFunction = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("count", count); // stale count value
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        Click increment button until count is 2, then click TestButton and see
        console log
      </h1>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={doSomething}>TestButton</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Temporary Solutions:**

1. Add `[count]` as dependency for `doSomething()` resolves the issue, but it prompts the error

> React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'count'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

2. Move `testFunction()` to above `doSomething()`,

```
  const testFunction = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("count", count); // no more stale
  }, [count]);

  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    // Do something else here
    testFunction();
  }, [testFunction]);
```

so when screen re-renders `testFunction` (which runs 1st) would get a new reference, and `doSomething` (which runs 2nd) would get a new `testFunction` reference. However the order of function declaration shouldn't matter as I understand functions are being hoisted up?

3. If use callback functions require the order in which it is defined, is there any linter that warns us? Or shouldn't eslint recommend [count] for doSomething()'s dependency, as it calls another useCallback function?

Answer (score 1):

I am hesitant to enforce `no-use-before-define` rule is because it collides with the common convention of putting StyleSheet at the bottom https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet (even official react channel follow it)

The linter I come across which solve this issue is: *(No idea why it works)*

`"no-use-before-define": ["error", { functions: false, classes: false, variables: false }],`

1. It catches premature useCallback reference.
2. Doesn't prompt error for StyleSheet at the bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`testFunction` is not defined when the code reaches the first `useCallback`. So the dependency array of `doSomething` is practically `[undefined]`. As a result, the first `useCallback` calls a stale `testFunction` that is no longer updated after the first render.

As you have said, moving `testFunction` above `doSomething` resolves the problem.

ESlint is actually right about the dependency array. `count` is unnecessary for `doSomething` as you don't directly use it. If you have correctly added as one of the dependencies of `doSomething`, `testFunction` will be updated as soon as `doSomething` is updated. I'm not sure why you think that changing their order will break the init code convention.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-18gpk?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Enforcing `no-use-before-define` would mean style declaration is on top, and any useEffect functions to be moved to bottom right before render().. also it does not solve the issue if I write it differently (see no.2 of my question)